# Htaccess - Redirect Google bot image to the right image URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Google bot Image is accessing the wrong image URL, how can I redirect it to the right one:

Wrong URL:

```
https://website.com/assets/https://website.com/assets/shop/product.jpg
```

Right URL:

```
https://website.com/assets/shop/product.jpg
```

What I have tried:

```
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)/assets/(.*)$ assets/$2  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/https://website.com/assets/(.*)$ assets/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/([a-z:/.]+)/assets/(.*)$ assets/$2  [R=301,L]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)//(.*)$ http://website.com/$1/$2/
```

None of the above works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} website.com/assets/shop/product.jpg$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ assets/shop/product.jpg [R,L]
```